# Using static files in a Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to get a file that's in my media directory to appear on an HTML template. I'm using the "Tango with Django" book as a tutorial.

Here is my `settings.py`:

```
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Here is `views.py`:

```
  def about(request):

    return render(request, 'rango/about.html', )
```

And my `about.html` template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{%load staticfiles%}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>About</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is the about page</h1>
<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}} {{cat.jpg}}"
     alt="cats are funny"/>
<div>
    <a href="/rango/"> Index </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know I must be missing something very obvious, but can't figure it out for the life of me!

Answer (score 3):

The `{{MEDIA_URL}}` tag is deprecated. Use the [`{% get_media_prefix %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#get-media-prefix) tag, instead.

```
<img src="{% get_media_prefix %}cat.jpg" alt="cats are funny"/>
```

From the documentation:

> Similar to the `get_static_prefix`, `get_media_prefix` populates a template variable with the media prefix `MEDIA_URL`.

When rendered, that `src` attribute will be equivalent to `/media/cat.jpg`. You may want to consider using `STATIC_ROOT` in your `settings.py`, instead, along with the `{% static %}` tag:

```
<img src="{% static 'cat.jpg' %}" alt="cats are funny"/>
```

Comment: I replaced the media_url tag with the get_media_prefix tag, and now it's saying that I didn't register/load that tag. Sorry, I'm a complete newbie to this.

Comment: @MatthewSheinberg: I've added a link to the documentation for `get_media_prefix`. It looks like you'll need to replace `{% load staticfiles %}` with `{% load static %}`, as the former is also deprecated. You may also want to verify that the book you're reading is guiding you in the correct version of Django; the current version being 1.11. [Here's a snippet from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/install/#verifying) that you can use to check your version.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problems should be errors in format.
Try the following two revisions:
1. in your render(), change "return render(request, 'rango/about.html', )" to "return render(request, 'rango/about.html') by deleting the last comma;
2. in your template file about.html, change .